# React to form auto-filling by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have two form elements, a `email` and a `password`. The `password` element must only be shown if something has been entered in the `email` element. That is, only if `email` is not empty.

```
<input id="email" name="email" onblur="if (jQuery(&quot;#email&quot;).val() === &quot;&quot;) { jQuery(&quot;#password&quot;).hide(); } else { jQuery(&quot;#password&quot;).show(); }" onchange="if (jQuery(&quot;#email&quot;).val() === &quot;&quot;) { jQuery(&quot;#password&quot;).hide(); } else { jQuery(&quot;#password&quot;).show(); }" onfocus="if (jQuery(&quot;#email&quot;).val() === &quot;&quot;) { jQuery(&quot;#password&quot;).hide(); } else { jQuery(&quot;#password&quot;).show(); }" placeholder="Email" style="width:360px;height:28px;margin-bottom:0px;" type="text">
```

As you see I am handling three events:

- `onfocus`: so that I react when the focus enters the email element
- `onblur`: so that I react when the focus leaves the email element
- `onchange`: so that I react when the email element changes

Actually, I only want to run the script whenever the email changes. I do not care about focus, but I am unable to handle a generic change event.

Besides, and this is my main problem, I am not able to react to the the event generated when the browser is auto-filling the form. Is there such an event? How can I handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser auto-filling occurs on initial page rendering. Have you tried checking the field in an "onReady" callback? Note that this event is only provided by higher level implementations like Jquery, not directly by the browser.

Example of ["ready" callback with jquery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): (updated to reflect the comments)

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#email").trigger('change');
  }, 200);
});
```

There is also an article explaining the "do it yourself way": http://dustindiaz.com/smallest-domready-ever

Comment: That is worth trying. How do I handle the onReady callback? Handling a javascript event is easy, since I just need to add the "onfocus" attribute to my input field. But how do I handle a jQuery callback. Could you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have implemented: `<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#email").trigger('change');
    });
  </script>`. It triggers the change event, but I would say it is too early, since the form is already not filled in, and nothing happens.

Comment: This is hackish but you can add a small timeout.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did too, and it worked (200ms), but of course makes the result dependent on how fast the browser performs form autocompletion. Anyway, I will accept this hackish option. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try disabling the browser autocomplete feaure by;

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" autocomplete="off">
```

or

```
<INPUT NAME="name" SIZE=40 AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF>
```

*Note. The first one is HTML5 `<form>` autocomplete Attribute*

Comment: I have just tried this and it works, but it completely switches off autocomplete (of course!), which is not what I want. I want my users to benefit from the autocompletion feature, but I want to display the form properly if it is autocompleted (which means, to show the password field)